# Jquery get all checked box and group by checkbox name

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have checboxes with different names:

Names - hours, and value - day. For example: value="1" means Monday, and name="0609" means from 06am - 09am.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="0609">
<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="0609">
...
<input type="checkbox" value="7" name="0609">

<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="0912">
<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="0912">
...
<input type="checkbox" value="7" name="0912">
```

I need to take all checked and non checked inputs and combine into array by the name like for example: If all days is checked except monday

```
'0609' => 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
```

How can I solve this ?

I was trying to get with .map but I get ungrouped values...

```
        var valuess = $('input:checked').map(function() {
            return this.value;
        }).get();
        console.log(valuess);
```

UPDATE:

```
        var obj = {}; // Define object

        // Loop over all checkboxes
        $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
            var name = $(this).attr('name'); // Get name of this checkbox
            var sThisVal = (this.checked ? "1" : "0");
            if (obj[name]) {
                obj[name].push(sThisVal); // Push value
            } else {
                obj[name] = [sThisVal]; // Create array and push value
            }
        });
        console.log(obj);
```

Comment: What do you need it for? If you're going to send it, it's probably easier to use names like `0609[]` and let the serverside figure it out ?

Comment: Yes I need to send by ajax to save in DB. with array like:             $hours = array(
                "0609" => array(1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
                "0912" => array(1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
                "1415" => array(1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
                "1518" => array(1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
                "1821" => array(1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
                "2124" => array(1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
                "2406" => array(1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
            );

Comment: Then use brackets in the name, and `serialize()` to get the data, and then figure out how to get the data in the right places on the server.

Comment: are you wanting 1 for checked and 0 for not checked - you are't storing the value of the checkbox anywhere or will this never change?  Instead of passing through 0 and 1, why not pass through only the values of the checked boxes?

Comment: Yes I want 1 for checked and 0 for not, and I will send through Ajax store in DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this:

```
var obj = {}; // Define object

// Loop over all checkboxes
$(':checkbox').each(function() {
    var name = $(this).attr('name'); // Get name of this checkbox

    if (obj[name]) {
        obj[name].push($(this).val()); // Push value
    } else {
        obj[name] = [$(this).val()]; // Create array and push value
    }
});
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Thank You a little bit of correction and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this

```
$("input[name='0609']").each( function () {
  //do somethin
});
```

Comment: This is not what `OP` wants. And if there are 100 checkboxes? 100 `each`?

Comment: He want all checkbox. so it is given.Already to specify name so name same to loop

Answer (score 0):

First, loop through all checkboxes, get their name attributes and make an array of then (without duplicates).

Then, loop through this array and create the object that logs out at the end.

Check the console and look at the object you are getting.

```js
var nm = [];
$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
  var name = $(this).attr('name'); 
  if ($.inArray(name, nm) == -1) {
    nm.push(name);
  }
});
var arr = [];
for (i=0;i<nm.length;i++) {
  var obj = {};
  obj.name = nm[i];
  var days = obj.days = {};
  $('input[name=' + nm[i] + ']').each(function() {    
    var that = $(this);
    var val = that.attr('value');
    if (that.is(':checked')) {
      days[val] = 1;
    } else {
      days[val] = 0;
    }
  });
  arr.push(obj);
}
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="0609">
<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="0609" checked>
<input type="checkbox" value="7" name="0609">
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="0912">
<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="0912">
<input type="checkbox" value="7" name="0912">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = {};
obj.checked = {};
obj.unchecked = {};
$(':checkbox').each(function() {
//console.log(this);
$this = $(this);
var key = $this.attr("checked") ? "checked" : "unchecked";
var index = $this.attr("name");
if(!obj[key][index]) {
  obj[key][index] = [];
}
obj[key][index].push($this.val());

});
```

console.log(obj);

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pratbhoir/d8p04tn5/

```
function getData() {
    var obj = {}; // Define object
    // Loop over all checkboxes
    $(':checkbox').each(function () {
        var name = $(this).attr('name'); // Get name of this checkbox
        var isChecked = 0;
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            isChecked = 1;
        }
        var dayIndex = $(this).val() - 1; //Get the dayIndex from value
        if (obj[name]) {
            obj[name][dayIndex] = isChecked; //set 1 to the value
        } else {
            obj[name] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]; // Create array and push value
            obj[name][dayIndex] = isChecked; //Set 1 to the array
        }
    });
    console.log(obj);
}
```